# Registry DWord value changing in vb

Tags: vb.net, registry, dword

I can't change the registry value in vb, please help.

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        regKey=Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", True)

regKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)

regKey.Close()
```

## Error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

> Requested registry access is not allowed.

Comment: That reg key limits write permissions to SYSTEM and Administrator(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute your application with admins rights :

- Projet's properties
- Show Windows parameters (this open app.manifest)

Change  `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`

to `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Comment: **Requested registry access is not allowed.** again ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it by opening visual studio as Administrator.